# Facebook Video Chat doesn't work after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: facebook, osx-mavericks

anyone experiencing the same issue? The video call icon does not appear on Facebook anymore after having upgraded to Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks.Any solution? I reinstalled the video calling and I gave the permission. Thanks.